# What is the preferred terminology for orthogonal complement of the kernel of an operator?

Tags: operator-theory, terminology

What is the best terminology for the **orthogonal complement of the kernel** of an operator?

Specifically, I am concerned about a linear operator between two Hilbert spaces; it is bounded, infinite-dimensional and has closed range.

I have seen the following terms used:

1. orthogonal complement of the kernel - too wordy
2. row space
3. pre-image
4. coimage
5. carrier - "[On Closed Range Operators in Hilbert Space](http://e-biblio.univ-mosta.dz/handle/123456789/11158),"     Messirdi; Ould-Ali, Mohand

An answer to "[What is the difference between kernel and nullspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235350/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-and-null-space/235353#235353)" suggests that **kernel** is a better choice for my operator because nullspace is more typically used for linear algebra. By analogy, I seek the best choice of terminology for the orthogonal complement of my operator's kernel. I rather like **carrier**, but I fear it may be rather obscure; I want the choice of words to be well-known by practitioners. (A little justification of your answer would be appreciated.) Thanks!

Comment: None of your 2, 3, 4, and 5 work for me. Why is "orthogonal complement of the kernel" too wordy for you?

Comment: I don't want to say "the person married to Bob's wife"; I want to say "Bob."

Comment: But "orthogonal complement of the kernel" is not analogous to "the person married to Bob's wife". You could define your own term, but then that won't be well-known by practitioners. It looks like practitioners are happy to say "orthogonal complement of the kernel".

Answer (score 1):

If the range of $T$ is closed, then so is the range of $T^*$. In that case, the orthogonal of the kernel of $T$ is simply the range of $T^*$.

Comment: In general it is just the closure of the range of $T^*$

Comment: True, but that's like referring to myself as "the thing that causes the reflection of the person I see in the mirror."  What terminology do you use for "orthogonal complement of the kernel"?

Comment: @EEatWork: the terminology I use is "orthogonal complement of the kernel".